# Facebook application authentication issue

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-authentication

I wrote the following code to authenticate a facebook application but instead of google many days it did not solve.
The problem is the when the application is first accessed user is prompt to application authentication dialog. when the user allows application it keeps blinking the url. neither shows dialog nor application. After closing the browser yes it runs fine. please can you find out what is the problem. I will be very thankful.

**Code:**

```
$canvas_page = "---my canvas url----"; //i removed actual url here!
// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
   $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page) ."&scope=email,read_stream";
     $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

     list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

     $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

     if (!empty($data["user_id"])) {
         echo 'Hello: '.$data["user_id"];
     }else{
         echo "What is the hell";
          echo("<script> location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work

```
 $canvas_page = "---my canvas url----"; //i removed actual url here! // Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).    $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="             . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page) ."&scope=email,read_stream";      $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];       list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);        $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);       if (!empty($data["user_id"])) {          echo 'Hello: '.$data["user_id"];      }else{          echo "What is the hell";           echo("<script> location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");      }
```

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
```

With **`top`**!